# How can I create a KOA path with a number?

Tags: koa, koa-router

I have an KOA endpoint. I have a `quantify` param that can only accept numbers, how can I enforce this directly in the KOA router?

```
.put('/cart/:product/:quantity', async ctx => {
    quantity = ctx.params.quantity;
    ctx.body = 'my code here';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this regexp:

```
'/cart/:product/:quantity(\\d+)'
```

^ matches quantities that only consist of numbers. `\d+` is the regexp, but you have to add another `\` for the router to convert it into a proper regexp since the route is a string.